# Image not being displayed in template using django-ads

Tags: django

I am new to django ads. I have created a project called mysite and inside that project I have created an app called advertisements.

See the below.[image]

The template which renders the add is as follows:

```
{% extends "advertisement/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load ads_tags %}

{% block css %} 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
      'advertisement/css/index.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 
      'advertisement/js/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Java Coffee House{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    {% render_ads_zone 'content' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my template, the link is working fine. However, the image is not loaded.
The console says Not Found: /advertisement/iphone.jpeg.

The admin page where I add the image dumps the image under the project folder.

Any ideas on to solve this error?

Comment: on serevr best way to server images are from nginx serevr

Comment: It worked....thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try check your STATIC_URL in the setting.py. There should be like STATIC_URL = '/static/'
Also after this inside static folder you must create a folder 'img' or if you would 'advertisement' and inside there must be place you *.jpeg files.

Right now you IDE cannot resolve your file, cause not see folder 'advertisement' inside static

Comment: The problem is the django_ads app does not place an image in a folder....so all images are in the project folder...they only way I got yo work is to setup the MEDIA_URL to point to /